# How calculate coefficiants for 3rd Butterworth Filter?

Tags: filter

I need to calculate `a[n]` and `b[n]` for 3rd Butterworth high pass filter. I know that I can calculate it with Octave formula `[b,a]=butter(3, fc/(fs/2), 'high')` but I work with different sampling frequencies and I need calculate these parameters for each signal (with different sampling for each).

Can you please tell me math formula for `a[n]` and `b[n]` parameters or math formula for `butter(3, ff)`?

Additionally: how to convert the filter formula `(s+1)(s2+s+1)` to `a[n]` and `b[n]` parameters?